# Memcached can't connect with php

Tags: php, memcached

I have centos 5.3 and I just installated memcached 1.4.2.
I can telnet it fine and do stats, etc., but when I try to connect to it over php I get an error that it can't connect.

---

It was SELinux.

Comment: Could you post some source code or the error?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you gave the exact wording/screenshot/log-lines.  I'm gonna bet its that you don't have the php memcache client library installed.  Try this:

```
yum install php-pecl-memcache
```

Comment: I do have it and i see memcached in my php info.